# Сбор данных из системных таблиц postgres 9.2. Какие права выдать пользователю для сбора?

Tags: postgresql

- есть приложение, которое забирает данные из системных таблиц postgres 9.2, например *pg_stat_activity*
- приложене не может поменять название системных таблиц из которых происходит забор (т.е. если создать view с названием test_stat, то приложение по прежнему будет пытаться забирать данные из *pg_stat_activity*)
- сервер СУБД нельзя обновить до какой-либо версии (например до 9.6)
- несмотря на доступ СУБД пользователя к системной бд postgres, при считывании данных из *pg_stat_activity* часть информации скрыто, например отображение текущего sql-запроса, вместо этого выводится "*insufficient privilege*"
- выдать права супер-пользователя на этого пользователя нет возможности

Как забрать данные, которые скрыты под *insufficient privilege*?

Answer (score 0):

В 9.2 `pg_stat_activity` [захардкожен весьма сильно](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_2_STABLE/src/backend/utils/adt/pgstatfuncs.c#L641): права на просмотр есть только у суперпользователя и у пользователя-хозяина этих сессий. В сущности, при описанных вами ограничениях остаётся только один путь.

Предусловия: запрос должен быть `from pg_stat_activity` и никак не `from pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity`, а так же у вас должна быть возможность выполнить два запроса от суперпользователя базы.

Действия:

- от обычного пользователя создадим отдельную схему в нужной базе:

  ```
  create schema monitoring;
  ```
- от суперпользователя в этой схеме создаём `security definer` хранимку:

  ```
  CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION monitoring.get_pg_stat_activity_priv() 
  returns setof pg_stat_activity 
  as 'select * from pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity;' 
  LANGUAGE 'sql' SECURITY DEFINER;
  ```
- от суперпользователя выдаём на функцию права на выполнение нужным пользователем (например, пользователю `melkij`):

  ```
  grant EXECUTE on FUNCTION monitoring.get_pg_stat_activity_priv() to melkij;
  ```
- от обычного пользователя проверяем

  ```
  select * from monitoring.get_pg_stat_activity_priv();
  ```

  права должны быть и все данные видны.
- Теперь исправляем доступность по нужному имени, для чего воспользуемся фокусом с `search_path`:

  ```
  alter user melkij set search_path to monitoring,pg_catalog,public;
  create view monitoring.pg_stat_activity as select * from monitoring.get_pg_stat_activity_priv();
  ```

  Затем необходимо переавторизоваться чтобы применился `alter user` либо сделать

  ```
  set search_path to monitoring,pg_catalog,public;
  ```
- наконец проверяем запрос

  ```
  select * from pg_stat_activity;
  ```

  Теперь в нём есть все данные.

Фокус с подменой `view` основан на том, что объекты без указания имени схемы ищутся в порядке указанном в `search_path`, куда всегда [входит `pg_catalog`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-schemas.html), обычно неявно в начале списка. Но если `pg_catalog` указать в `search_path` явно, то можно попросить искать системные объекты сначала в другом месте и тем самым подменять их поведение для отдельных пользователей.

---

> несмотря на доступ СУБД пользователя к системной бд postgres

Никак между собой не связано. Это не системная БД, это просто автоматически созданная БД во время инициализации кластера.

Кстати, 9.2 уже не поддерживается и весьма рекомендую обновить базу.